# How to add a fully transparent to semi-transparent gradient in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have a situation where I want to add an image view doing the same effect as this app

[image: Screenshot]

As you notice there is a drawable or something hiding the bottom side of the view adding a transparent gradient. How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use fadingEdge attribute of the listView in your xml. Make a listView, then add items xml (images in particular as you've mentioned above).

`android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"`

Comment: And how can this be possible with a Recyclerview (my current view)

Comment: I searched for a Recyclerview view equivalent and found an identical code as you wrote above. Thanks!

Comment: android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"

This will workout for you. And sure, anytime, bro! :)

Answer (score 5):

Place this drawable in the bottom of your layout:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" > 
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the answer as this draws a gradient from "white" to transparent.

Comment: You have to change the color to what you need

Comment: In your example start color is blue.

Comment: And what if the background is an image not a solid color?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change alpha value of that image View. Go through
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823607/how-to-make-transparent-gradient) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android) for more details.